# How to parse S3 response Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

Request to S3, **v2** API.

```
$result = $client->getBucketLifecycleConfiguration(array(
    // Bucket is required
    'Bucket' => 'string',
));
```

I get the following response

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model::__set_state(array(
   'structure' => NULL,
   'data' => 
  array (
    'Rules' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'ID' => 'Test',
        'Filter' => 
        array (
          'Prefix' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
        'Status' => 'Enabled',
        'NoncurrentVersionExpiration' => 
        array (
          'NoncurrentDays' => '250',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'RequestId' => 'E83571AFC306FFFD',
  ),
))
```

I want to parse this object!

Tried to get data like following `$result->data` got **NULL**

I tried to typecast it to **array** but got the following array index. it seems I am doing it wrong.

```
array (
  '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'structure' => NULL,
  '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'data' => 
  array (
    'Rules' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'ID' => 'Test',
        'Filter' => 
        array (
          'Prefix' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
        'Status' => 'Enabled',
        'NoncurrentVersionExpiration' => 
        array (
          'NoncurrentDays' => '250',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'RequestId' => 'E83571AFC306FFFD',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-models.html

According to link, you can convert the Model to array using `$result->toArray()` method or access directly the result attribute you want through array keys, i.e. `$result['Rules']`.